# How to convert coma delimited string into python dictionary?

Tags: python

Please help me with the following issue: I have coma delimited strings and value that related to these strings. The number of comas is unpredictable and can be limited by 6. I have to convert it into python dictionary. For example:

```
aa.bb.cc 6 =>  mydict['aa']['bb']['cc']=6
aa.bb.dd.ee 8 = mydict['aa']['bb']['dd']['ee']=8
```

My python version is 2.7.9

Comment: Do you want nested dictionaries (as shown) or one dictionary with all the fields as keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict as defd
dic = defd(dict)

def create_dict(astr):
    keys, val = astr.split(' ')
    keys = keys.split('.')
    val = int(val)
    prevdic = dic
    for j, k in enumerate(keys):
        if j == len(keys)-1:
            prevdic[k] = val
        elif k not in prevdic:
            prevdic[k] = defd(dict)
        prevdic = prevdic[k]

create_dict('aa.bb.cc 6')
create_dict('aa.bb.dd.ee 8')
dic['aa']['bb']['cc'] ## returns 6
dic['aa']['bb']['dd']['ee'] ## returns 8
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you want one dictionary with multiple keys (you do say "*a* dictionary") :

```
import re

s1 = 'a.bb.dd.ee 8'
s2 = 'aa.bb.cc 6'

def create_d(s):
    fields = re.split(r'[. ]', s)
    v = int(fields.pop())

    d = { field:v for field in fields }
    return d

mydict = create_d(s1)
print mydict

mydict.update(create_d(s2))
print mydict
```

Gives:

```
{'a': 8, 'ee': 8, 'dd': 8, 'bb': 8}
{'a': 8, 'aa': 6, 'bb': 6, 'ee': 8, 'dd': 8, 'cc': 6}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try following simple code

```
str1 = 'aa.bb.cc 6'
str2 = 'aa.bb.cc.dd 8'
dictstr = {}
strdelim = str1.split(' ')
dictstr[tuple(strdelim[0].split('.'))] = strdelim[1]
strdelim = str2.split(' ')
dictstr[tuple(strdelim[0].split('.'))] = strdelim[1]
print dictstr
```

Result

```
{('aa', 'bb', 'cc'): '6', ('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'): '8'}
```